# office.context.mailbox is undefined

Tags: outlook-addin, office-js

when i am trying open a pop up in outlook.i am  getting office.context.mailbox undefined in pop up controller.But i got office object in controller.Please suggest.Code is below

```js
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('wpoffice')
        .component('externalTrack', 
            templateUrl: 'app/components/externalTrack/external-track_template.html',
            controller: ExternalTrackController,
            bindings: {}
        });
​
    /** ngInject*/
​
    function ExternalTrackController($rootScope, $scope, $timeout, appData, ngNotify,$q,trackingService) {
        var self = this;
        self.$onInit = activate;
        function activate() {
            console.log(Office)
            console.log(Office.context.mailbox);
    }
}
})();
```

Comment: Did you call "Office.initialize" in your pop up page?

Comment: yeah i have iniatialized office in pop up page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access most functions in a pop up launched by the dialog API and I see no reason it would work if you used window.open either.

`The messageParent function is one of only two Office APIs that can be called in the dialog box. (The other is Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported)` [Dialog API docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins)